# combining silhouette scores of data samples

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a big array that I need to cluster and calculate the silhouette score for the purpose of learning the best number of clusters for my data. 
The problem is that due to `np.dot` limitations I get `MemoryError` when I try to run `silhouette_score(X, c_labels)`

I read the source code of [silhouette_score](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py#L22), and I found is that it calls `np.mean` on the result of another method `silhouette_samples`. So, I thought maybe I should send the data in batches and get their mean. So, I ran an experiment. I created a 2d array of 10,000x 10,000 numbers. Then I ran the clusterer then I calculated their score like this:

```
testX = np.random.random((N, N))
b = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=10)
c_labels = b.fit_predict(testX)
s = silhouette_score(testX, c_labels)
```

and s = -0.0001115591406734728
Then I ran the batched version:

```
ss = []
lastIndex = 0
ss.append(silhouette_score(testX[:batch], c_labels[:batch]))
lastIndex += batch
while lastIndex < len(testX):
    ss.append(silhouette_score(testX[lastIndex:lastIndex+batch], c_labels[lastIndex:lastIndex+batch]))
    lastIndex += batch
np.mean(ss)
```

and I get -6.7414138934508567e-05 which is very far from the original result.

So, my question is: is there a way to do this?

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer to your question but could you not use the `sample_size` parameter to overcome your memory issue?

Comment: The source code is doing mean of `silhouette_samples` and you are doing mean of `silhouette_score`

Comment: @ncfirth thank you this actually solved the problem add this as a solution

Comment: I'm sorry @ncfirth but this solution will only calculate the score for just one sample of the data.

Comment: Not just one sample, it will calculate it on a random subset of the data rather than all of your data. For example if you set `sample_size=1` then it will randomly pick one sample and calculate the `silhouette_score` for it, however if you set `sample_size=1000` it will randomly sample 1000 samples and calculate `silhouette_score` for that.

Comment: ok but I need it for all the data

Comment: Read the *definition* of silhouette, then think about this thoroughly. Don't just attempt to reverse engineer, solve the math first. Then you will see how you can sample to approximate Silhouette. And no, you *don't* want this for all data, because of runtime. It's not only quadratic memory, but also quadratic time. Silhouette is not scalable.